# Poor running after head gasket replacement.

Tags: engine, pontiac, head-gasket, grand-prix

2002 Grand Prix 3.1 v6. I have just changed blown head gaskets on my car. I have also replaced radiator water pump. Hoses belt spark plugs starter .working on getting new battery.  I have bypassed the heater core.

First day drove fine till late afternoon started getting hot .
Second day same thing started getting hot. Was building up pressure bleed the coolant spurting out water then just air no steady stream of water?
Third day started car. When in p and n the idle runs high when in r and d bogs down really bad almost dieing. And transmission wouldn't shift.
Any help please i really need to get back to work. Heidi

Comment: Welcome to the site! Did you use new head bolts with your head gasket replacement? Is the check engine light on? If so, what are the codes?